# Does anyone know how to get Google+ user's home/work address(not email) from Google API?

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth

Currently we retrive user's profile by [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) API, and scopes are `profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login`.

But no matter user sets their home/work address as public, we still can't get address from reponse.

Did I use the wrong API or scopes?

Comment: Have you found a way to do this? Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#email-scopes) for scopes.

- `email` gives access to "the user's Google account email address."
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read` gives access to "the user's Google account email address, as well as any public, verified email addresses in the user's Google+ profile."

Comment: Sorry, I mean the address where user lives or works, not the email address. :)